# Accessing node value in paragraph twig template

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I'm writing a twig template for a paragraph. I'd like to access a text field value from the page/node where this type of paragraph will be added.

Specifically, I'd like to access the value of a text field titled 'field_runner_id'. I access this value in my page/node twig template like this:

```
content.field_runner_id|field_value
```

I've tried a handful of techniques (listed below) to access that field value within my paragraph template but am having no success.

How can I refer to a parent page's field value within a paragraph template?

I've found a few posts and articles that address this issue, and am able to get details about the parent node, such as the title and nid but not fields that it contains.

Eg this post: https://mark.ie/blog/printing-values-of-a-parent-node-from-a-drupal-paragraphs-field
...helped me to get the parent page and nid via adding this within my paragraph template:

```
{% set parent = paragraph._referringItem.parent.parent.entity %}
{{ parent.title.value }}
{{ parent.nid.value }}
```

I've also tried these, among others, with no success:

```
{{ parent.content.field_runner_id.value }}
{{ parent.content.field_runner_id[0] }}
{{ parent.content.field_runner_id|field_value }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is easier then you think:

```
{% set parentNode = paragraph.parentEntity %}
<!-- parentNode is already the node object, so now you can access any field directly without going through the content object --->

{{ parentNode.field_runner_id.value }}
```

What will make your live also more easy in general, is to install the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and [devel_kint_extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_kint_extras) module for development.

Then you can explore the complicated drupal object structure like this and find the right field value:

```
{{kint(parentNode)}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Preface: Do not use that method from that blog, there is a better method.

1. `something._referringItem` is not cache safe, so better not use this inside Twig templates.
2. `something._referringItem` doesn't perform any access checks
3. `paragraph._referringItem.parent.parent.entity` is possibly the longest and most confusing alternative to write `paragraph.parentEntity`

---

So, now the real answer :-)

`paragraph.parentEntity` is returning the raw parent entity object (very similar to the `paragraph` variable) but it does not include a render array like `content`. So you neither need `.content` nore you need `|field_value`.

Instead head directly for the field value `parent.field_on_hostnode.0.value`

---

**More info about variables in entity templates:**

`content` = complete render array of an entity

`content.field_something` = render array of a single field

`content.field_something|field_value` = get raw field value back from a render array (requires "Twig field value" module)

`entity` = raw entity object (replace entity with `node` in node template, `paragraph` in paragraph template, etc).

`entity.field_something.value` = not recommended, will behave differently depending on field type and field cardinality

`entity.field_something.getValue()` = get an array of raw field values, works for all field types and all field cardinalities

`entity.field_something.0.value` = get the first raw data field value (for plaintext fields, numbers, emails, telephone field; will not work with links, images, entity references...)

`entity.field_something.0.name_of_database_column` = get the first raw data subvalue `name_of_database_column` of field_something (this could be `format` in a formatted text field, `end_value` in a daterange field, `target_id` in a entity reference field,...)

**Entity reference field only:**

*Note that the following methods are not cache-safe, not language-aware and do not perform access checks.*

`entity.field_reference.0.target_id` = get the numeric ID of the first referenced child entity

`entity.field_reference.0.entity` = the first referenced child entity object (no render array!)

`entity.field_reference.0.entity.getTranslation('de')` = get the german translation of the first child object

**Paragraphs only:**

`paragraph.parentEntity` = the direct parent entity object (no render array!)

Comment: Also importantly when bypassing rendering you may lose access checks.

Comment: Good hint, I added this to the answer. AFAIK the same is true for any `field_foo.0.entity`

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you @Hudri